# how to change text in gmail reply through javascript chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

(the answer doesn't have to be necessarily chrome extension)
I am making a extension for desabled people and was wondering if there is a way to change text in a reply field in gmail so far this is what I got it does not work in the console anything that would work in the console would be appreciated

`document.getElementsByTagName('aria-label="Message body"').innerHTML = "cool";`

They seem to have a weird way of doing things there I am lost and would be grateful to any help.

*Just go to gmail and go to a email in your inbox hit reply and try to change the text through the console*.